# Using ClassyCountdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, timestamp, countdown

I wanted to use Countdown from this site: http://www.class.pm/files/jquery/classycountdown/

I edited it to Countdown to my fixed date, but does not work:  http://jsfiddle.net/d7asx17j/

When you change the value END examples of these steps, it works, but not deducted until the date that I want

```
end: '1430438401',
now: $.now()
```

This is how it works:

```
end: $.now() + 1000,
now: $.now()
```

Do not you advise me where the problem may be?
Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't work in the fiddle because *none* of the external resources you have defined are loading - they all 404.

Comment: Seems to work fine if you don't use an epoch date. Are you sure it supports that method? It's not mentioned anywhere in the documentation http://jsfiddle.net/d7asx17j/1/

Comment: What would Countdown, which would unable to count down to the date they need? In